# How do I set up hotkeys for a xterm?

Tags: configuration, xterm

When I do a ssh to an OpenSuse machine and use yast I have to use tab intead of alt+y for help for example, I don't know what else to say...

[image]

My question is how to set up this to have a propper xterm console.

additin:xterm and/or **LXterminal** maybe this one has some features to add, really don't know.

Comment: I can't work out what the question is here? What terminal are you using? Actual `xterm` or something else? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Are you close enough (network wise) to use remote X windows, perhaps?

Comment: using xterm... I want to be able to use alt+<whatever> when use ssh on a opensuse machine (the yast console), just like when you use xterm on the opensuse it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `xterm`, press the Control key and at the same time left-click somewhere on the xterm window.

A menu should appear, where you can select "Meta Sends Escape" that should do what you ask

[image]

To set this option as default, create a file of name `.Xresources` in you home, and put the following line into it:

```
XTerm.metaSendsEscape: true
```

then restart your session.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to the accepted answer, `XTerm.metaSendsEscape` is now `XTerm.vt100.metaSendsEscape`. According to the documentation for xterm:

> The following resources are specified as part of the vt100 widget
> (class VT100).  They are specified by patterns such as
> “XTerm.vt100.NAME”.
>
> If  your  xterm  is  configured  to  support the “toolbar”, then those patterns need an extra level for the form-widget which
> holds the toolbar and vt100 widget.  A wildcard between the top-level
> “XTerm” and the “vt100” widget makes the resource settings work for either, e.g., “XTerm*vt100.NAME”

(metaSendsEscape is among the resources specified in the VT100 class)

The full declaration in Xresources should be

```
XTerm.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true
```