# Term, Xterm or Uxterm?

Tags: command-line

I'm an average home user, but still sometimes use terminal for simple tasks. When I type "terminal" in unity, it offers me three choices - but what`s the difference? I hate always choosing randomly and thinking about what I did.

Comment: It's very cool if you are constantly using i.e. mc (midnight commander) and you want to work with all existing shortcuts :D. Because some short keys don't work on xterm with menu gnome support and it is an advantage in mc :D. Good example of this could be shourtcut F10 or another. If you try to use it in standard gnome-terminal in mc it doesn't work, but on xterm works very well.

Comment: *"Canonical’s Brian Quigley explains: “Xterm takes up two menu items (xterm and uxterm) and doesn’t provide any more functionality than gnome-terminal. "* [Someone Finally Asks Why Ubuntu Has 3 Terminal Apps…](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/ubuntu-xterm-uxterm-terminal-default)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Terminal is, in Ubuntu default software, the gnome-terminal. XTerm is... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm. UXTerm is XTerm with support to Unicode characters.
The main difference between XTerm and Terminal is that the gnome-terminal has more features, while XTerm is minimalistic (though it has features that are't in gnome-terminal, but they are more advanced).

Comment: Unicode is a big deal.

Comment: As far as I can see in both Xterm and UXterm, Unicode characters such as those in `cat ~/Desktop/examples.desktop` look absolutely identical, with or without TrueType fonts selected via Control+right click. How exactly are these two terminal emulators different?

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Ubuntu, you should also have `gnome-terminal` installed. For Kubuntu the default terminal is `konsole`, and for Lubuntu is `lxterminal`.

All three are good choices.

To be Desktop Environment independent as much as possible, I would choose  `lxterminal`.

`xterm`, and `uxterm` are good but they use ugly looking fonts, and pose some problems in regards to keystrokes (see [How do I set up hotkeys for a xterm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90784/how-do-i-set-up-hotkeys-for-a-xterm)).

Comment: You`re kidding, they can`t add multiple versions of software because of different fonts. Bugging people, because it makes sense to  1% of users and costs so little disk space? There must be serious differences.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas: I don't say they are identical from the functional point of view, and I don't say they only differ in fonts (that is somewhat configurable, by the way), but two software don't need to have "serious differences" to be both included in the repositories. The choice is left to user's preferences.

Comment: xterm doesn't depend on other software, which may be of use in the event you accidentally uninstall something.

Comment: You can use truetype fonts (and anti-aliasing) for xterm with control-right click (hold), select "truetype fonts"

Comment: My point is, that including almost identical software forces users to make choise which they don`t need. You can compare it to overdocumenting, or adding a second poweroff button.

Comment: Hi @JustinasDūdėnas and enzotib - perhaps the result of your inquisitive and insightful discussions could be distilled into improvements on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_terminal_emulators wiki for the benefit of all global users?

Comment: Bitmap fonts are not ugly ;) But some of the defaults can be poor depending on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 8):

The default is "terminal", which is `gnome-terminal`.

You can also summon one with a hotkey <kbd>ctrl-alt-T</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Gnome-terminal is generally more of a resource hog than xterm and rxvt.
Also, gnome-terminal's install size is generally around ten times larger than
xterm's.

By default, urxvt uses a feature called fast scrolling. This causes the
terminal emulator to not always update the window when the content changes. If
a program is outputting a significant amount of data to the terminal emulator,
fast scrolling can result in a noticeable performance boost. Xterm has this
option disabled by default, but you can enable it by putting `XTerm*fastScroll:
True` in your `.Xresources` file. Gnome-terminal does not seem to have this
feature.

Gnome-terminal has profiles that allow you to define and quickly switch between
configurations.

Comment: For gnome-terminal, the VSZ (virtual size) is about 5-8 times larger and RSS (resident set size) is about 4-5 times larger than for xterm. But this is for `gnome-terminal-server`, which allows to open as many windows as you like. If you open as many xterm windows, the memory requirements will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

For an average user, `xterm` and `uxterm` are pretty useless.

I personally rely on `gnome-terminal` even for advanced usage. I simply remove the other two, so I don't be bothered with them showing in my apps search.

Comment: How exactly are xterm and uxterm useless? I'm much rather press F10 in xterm than Esc, 0 in gnome-terminal, and [with true-type fonts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95435/term-xterm-or-uxterm#comment209723_95450) xterm looks awesome.

Comment: @DanDascalescu One can simply type [Alt][0] and it does the same thing. Also, `gnome-terminal` font looks spectacular and you don't have to do `xterm -fa font -fs 10` before hand after hitting [Alt][F2]. I guess you could setup gnome-terminal to open up xterm like that and exit. Another downfall of xterm is its lightweight-ness. It's archaic; it's like vim vs gedit. Unless you don't have a modern computer, just don't use xterm. You can't zoom in; you don't have a menu; you *can't* **COPY AND PASTE** (the most annoying)! Basically, use xterm if you need to use ed to edit without much cpu usage.

Comment: @dylnmc I can copy and paste in `xterm` with <Ctrl><Ins> and <Shift><Ins>.  Copying doesn't go to the X clipboard by default, but one can check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm