# Make xterm copy and paste work on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I try to copy and paste in xterm.

This is generally a solved question as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm) but on my laptop (ASUS x551ma) I have problems.

I highlight a text which assume copies it to the clipboard.

The paste is problematic.

There are two ways to make paste:

- middle button
- shift + insert

I have a mouse with just 2 buttons and pressing them simultaneously does not work.

The only insert button I see is the one on the  number zero.

When I press shift + insert I write 0.

How can I paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-ASUS-X501-X501A-X501U-X501EI-X501XE-X501XI-Laptop-US-Keyboard-Black-/231316577134?pt=US_Laptop_Replacement_Keyboards&hash=item35db8adb6e) image, you should have an <kbd>insert</kbd> key if you use <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>del</kbd>.
Alternatively, you should be able to use <kbd>0</kbd> as insert if you disable num lock.

However, you should be able to get middle click emulation working, I am surprised it doesn't out of the box. The traditional way is to add this line to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "whatever"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
EndSection
```

But you can also do it graphically by installing `gpointing-device-settings` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/160175/85695). In fact, that post gives various ways of achieving this.