# How to enable cut or copy-paste in xterm

Tags: command-line, xterm

I regularly uses xterm for web browsing because of its image rendering property but the one thing which makes xterm difficult comparing to terminal is the copy/cut paste availability in terminal program. I have found this [method](https://askubuntu.com/a/541730/158636) and according to this i saved the below code in `.Xdefaults` file in home directory

```
xterm -ls -xrm 'XTerm*selectToClipboard: true'&
```

After the implementation of this code I am able to select text in xterm but not able to copy or cut paste (using mouse or keyboard shortcuts ctrl+c etc) any text from or to the xterm.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shall not include that line in `.Xdefaults`. Thus shalt thou start the program.

```
xterm -ls -xrm 'XTerm*selectToClipboard:true' &
```

Or with `.Xdefaults`:

Add this line:

```
XTerm*selectToClipboard:true
```

and reload the configuration

```
xrdb ~/.Xdefaults
```

Comment: It worked i am able to copy from xterm to a notepad but viseversa its not working.

Comment: @Eka Shift+Insert

Comment: Better to use `~/.Xresources`

Comment: Note that if you use `-class ${CLASS}` to launch `xterm` the corresponding flag becomes `-xrm ${CLASS}.*.selectToClipboard:true` so if you have separate xterm window classes, settings are tracked separately.

Answer (score 10):

You can edit the `XTerm` file using `vim` or `nano` (I use `vim`):

```
vim /home/your_user_name/XTerm
```

Add this:

```
XTerm*Background: black
XTerm*Foreground: green
XTerm*SaveLines: 2000
XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu mono
XTerm*faceSize: 12
XTerm*rightScrollBar: true
XTerm*ScrollBar: true
XTerm*scrollTtyOutput: false
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \
      Shift Ctrl<Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\ 
      Shift Ctrl<Key>V: insert-selection(PRIMARY) \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Down>: select-start() \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Motion>: select-extend() \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Up>: select-end(CLIPBOARD) \n\
```

Save and close with:

```
:wq
```

Open `xterm`:

```
xterm &
```

The above configuration does four things:

1. Select and copy text into `xterm`:

   - Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
   - Click the <kbd>left mouse button</kbd>.
   - Select your text.
   - Click the <kbd>right mouse button</kbd> to add it to the clipboard.
2. Paste text into `xterm` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
3. Show the scrollbar.
4. Customize the font.

Comment: How would you do Ctrl + Shift + c for interrput?

Comment: You must stop pressing the left mouse button and  the Shiht key.

Comment: @Jayjayyy You are right! Then you can ignore it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Handling shortcuts in Xterm**

[image]

In `Edit keyboard shortcuts` you can than set what you want.
Obviously if some key combination is taken you have to clear that assignment first from current use in order to use it for your commands.