# How to copy paste in Xterm using Ctr l+ C , Ctrl + V in Ubuntu

Tags: xterm, code-blocks

How to copy and paste in Xterm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> like Windows in Ubuntu 16.04? (Using codeblocks)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/617629/how-to-enable-cut-or-copy-paste-in-xterm?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've no clue about Xterm but if you choose a Terminal instead (which most likely is the superiour application anyway) the corresponding shortcuts are <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> respectively.