# Diferrence between Uxterm, Xterm and terminal?

Tags: command-line, root

Is there a difference in authority between the Xterm and the Ubuntu terminal?
I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and I'm worried if I used the Xterm that I somehow have root privileges and I can harm the PC?

Comment: This question is answered better than I can at th is earlier protected answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95435/term-xterm-or-uxterm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the emulator does not start with a "#" as a prompt it is not a root session.

It probably is also not possible to use an emulator out of the box that starts with a root session unless you (after installing) manually set it up to start with a root session. It somehow must have your admin password and that can only be issued manually (or by the system but that needs altering the sudoers file also by you).

So any emulator will be as safe as any other emulator.

In general:

Ubuntu is out of the box as secure as possible. So a method from an application to directly use root would not be allowed to be included in the repositories I would assume. A root session would not be the Ubuntu way. We use sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, I used all of them and the only thing that changes is the design =)

Comment: **Not only the design**. Terminal is gnome-terminal. [XTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) is the standard terminal emulator for the X Window System.  UXTerm is XTerm with support to Unicode characters. Read [more](http://askubuntu.com/a/141305/329173).